# Parameters passed into function change from (1) and (-1) to (n) - why is this?

Tags: javascript

When someone onclicks one of the buttons, plusDivs is called and a numerical value (i think a function parameter) is sent to plusDivs, which is plusdivs (1) or (-1) - but when the numbers arrive at plusDivs they are now referred to as (n) why is this?

I am trying to find out the exact javascript technical term for describing (1) and (-1) changing into (n) when they reach the plusDivs function in the script and how this works more clearly.

```
 <button style="border:none; font-size: 22px;background-color:black; 
 color:white; position:fixed; top:40%; left:5%" class="w3-button w3-black w3-
 display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
 <button id="rightbutton" style="border:none; font-size: 22px;background-
 color:black; color:white;position:fixed; top:40%; right:2%" class="w3-button 
 w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
```

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: This is called `scope` and `shadowing`. `n` does refer to two different variables (parameters)

Comment: Ah - does anyone else have some clear input?

Comment: `1` and `-1` are called "arguments". `n` is called a "parameter". `n` represents the value that was passed into the `plusDivs` function. This is extremely basic stuff in almost any programming language. Have you read any JavaScript tutorials or anything? [Here's one place to start](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/a-functional-programmers-introduction-to-javascript-composing-software-d670d14ede30)

Comment: JLRishe - thanks for your input but I am not sure you  understand my question. I understand how it's working, I am more trying to find out the background to why (1) and (-1) are now referred to as (n) once they reach the plusDivs function. What is the exact javascript rule which describes why (n) can accept multiple values? so I can read up about this and be better informed for next time I come across it.

Comment: @JonasW. There is no shadowing involved here.

Comment: @Emma45 _"What is the exact javascript rule which describes why (n) can accept multiple values?"_ I don't know of a term for this "rule" and I don't think you really need a term for it in order to understand it. The whole point of function parameters is that they can take on any value that is passed into the function. That's just how functions work, in their most basic manifestation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to analyze this:
plusDivs(n) is a function that receives a parameter(n).
-- parameters are the name/s (n) listed in the function definition

so when you call this function on the onclick, you should pass an argument(-1) or (1).
-- arguments are the value/s (1/-1) passed to the function

you can also create a function that receives more than 1 parameter such as
plusDivs(n, x, y) but when you call this function, you should pass 3 values/arguments such as plusDivs(3,4,2)

hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Function parameters are the names listed in the function definition. 
Function arguments are the real values passed to (and received by) the function.

In your case (n) is parameter and 1 and -1 are arguments!

Comment: Thanks Sam for your input :)